# Adding UIButton to toolbar swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, toolbar

so I have read other stack overflow ages and none seem to help me. I have a piece of code that creates my UIButton which is here:

```
let haveAccountButton: UIButton = {
    let HColor = UIColor(red: 89/255, green: 156/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1)
    let HFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    let HSColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 47/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)

    let HButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string:
        NSLocalizedString("Already have an account?", comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: HFont])
    attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString(" Sign In", comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: HSColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: HFont]))
    HButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signinAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    HButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)

    return HButton
}()
```

I already set navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false in viewDidLoad. my question is how do I make the button appear in the toolbar?

UPDATE: The way this code will run currently without the toolbar is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SignUpControllerSave: UIViewController {


let haveAccountButton: UIButton = {
    let HColor = UIColor(red: 89/255, green: 156/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1)
    let HFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    let HSColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 47/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)

    let HButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string:
        NSLocalizedString("Already have an account?", comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, NSAttributedString.Key.font: HFont])
    attributedTitle.append(NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString(" Sign In", comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: HSColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: HFont]))
    HButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signinAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    HButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)

    return HButton
}()

//potential gradient background if wanted
func setGradientBackground() {
    let top_Color = UIColor(red: 203/255, green: 215/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let bottom_Color = UIColor(red: 181/255, green: 199/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [top_Color, bottom_Color]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Membership", comment: "")
    setupHaveAccountButton()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    setGradientBackground()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

@objc func signinAction() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

fileprivate func setupHaveAccountButton() {
    view.addSubview(haveAccountButton)
    haveAccountButton.anchors(top: nil, topPad: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                              bottomPad: 8, left: view.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: view.rightAnchor,
                              rightPad: 0, height: 20, width: 0)
}
```

}

UPDATE: The previous answer did allow for the button to now be on the toolbar, but the button target action does not work. I have tried adding .sizeToFit() where I can and looked at a lot of websites all to no avail. Anyone know how I can go about solving the button target issue?

Comment: Show the code that attempts to use this `haveAccountButton` property.

Comment: Unrelated but variable names should start with lowercase letters. It will make your code much easier to read.

Comment: will fix in the future, but I updated to show how I currently display the code

Comment: If you want to show the toolbar, why do you have lots of code to hide the toolbar?

Comment: I am sorry I had it as true because it looked bad with it there. it is supposed to be false and the haveAccountButton is supposed to be in there

Comment: What about all of the other code to hide the toolbar? And where is your attempt to put the button in the toolbar?

Comment: I do not know how to even start to put the button on the tool bar

Comment: I don't think you should use `UIButton` with toolbar, use `UIBarButtonItem` instead

Comment: Sometime I use a customized `UIView` as my tool bar, if the native `UIToolBar` cannot fit my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work the way you want:

```swift
class SignUpControllerSave: UIViewController {

    /* the other code you posted can be used without changes */

    fileprivate func setupHaveAccountButton() {
        toolbarItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(customView: haveAccountButton)
        ]
    }

}
```

As this seems to cause problems with regards to the click handler, try this (which looks almost the same – except for the font size):

```swift
class SignUpControllerSave: UIViewController {


    fileprivate func setupHaveAccountButton() {
        let haveAccountLabel = UILabel()
        haveAccountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize)
        haveAccountLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Already have an account?", comment: "")
        haveAccountLabel.textColor = .lightGray

        toolbarItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(customView: haveAccountLabel),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign In", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.signinAction)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        ]
        navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 47/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: for some reason I cannot click on the button now. it doesn't take me to the page I need to.